# Publish WebApi to Subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, twitter, asp.net-web-api

I have an out-of-the-box Visual Studio 2013 SPA using WebApi.  I added Twitter authentication to Startup.Auth.cs and all of it works just fine when I publish to the root of an IIS web site or when I debug in VS with localhost.

What I can't figure out is how to publish the project to a subfolder like this:

[image]

In other words, http://localhost/api

The site itself works.  It is the ReturnUrl from Twitter that always redirects to http://localhost/#  It includes the correct access_token but in this format:

http://localhost/#access_token=fzgSLjF4W0QAHlhsNFZI...

If I manually type in "api/" before #access_token it opens the default Index page and is authenticated via Twitter.  I have tweaked every setting on the Twitter side, javascript, and .cs.  I just can't find a solution other than Publish to a root web site.  I would like to publish to a subfolder application.

Suggestions?

Comment: What are your reasons to publish it in a _subfolder_? I would suggest you look into Virtual Host in IIS.

Comment: The callback url in twitter - does it contain /api?

Comment: yes it does.  i have also tried http://127.0.0.1/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through each folder, I noticed one folder that I did not check - Providers.  And in there is a class called ApplicationOAuthProviders.cs.  Once I changed values in that file, social logins started to redirect correctly.

There are a number of changes that need to change to publish to a subfolder; they are:

- **ApplicationOAuthProvider**: context.Request.Uri, "/YourSubfolder/"
- **app.datamodel.js**:  self.userInfoUrl = "YourSubfolder/me"; (remove first slash)
- **app.viewmodel.js** :   window.location = "/YourSubfolder/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
- **WebApiConfig.cs**: routeTemplate: "YourSubfolder/{controller}/{id}"

Answer (score 8):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818733/2718874)

Use the Visual Studio "Web Deploy" publish method.

Set "Site name" to
`localhost/api` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I am going to test this.  Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding virtual directory in your IIS website?
I have my API as separate project and I can refer to it by using www.your-web-site/API-subfolder
To do it go to your IIS -> context menu on your website. Then:
[image]

And add alias (subfolder-name) and Physical path to your API project.
It should work

Comment: I tried that but got an error saying that it needed to be a web application.

Comment: Try creating API web application, Include your WebApi project in there and then refer virtual directory to your API web application.

Comment: @Lokki..i am trying to host my web api as virtual directory. I am able to see directory listing but when i am trying to hit the controller i am not able to do that.Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I went thru hell with this and here is what I do to fix that issue:

When on **Content View** just click on the subfolder and select **"Convert To Application".** Thats it.

Then just click on the newly created Application and hit browse, it will show you the default page of the Web API Project.